# How to do simple ternary in React with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React and TypeScript. I cannot find a solution for this on Google.

I have a component that outputs an image. I want to wrap that image in an `<a>` tag if there is a  given URL prop. I am unsure how to write the logic simply enough.

From looking online I have written the following:

```
const imageBlock = ({
  imageSrc,
  imageAlt,
  imageTitle,
  imageLink,
}: imageBlockProps) => {
  return (
    imageLink && (
      <a href={imageLink}>
    )
      <img src={imageSrc} alt={imageAlt} title={imageTitle} />

    imageLink && (
      </a>
    )
  )
};
```

But I cannot get it to work.

Would anyone know the best way to do it?

Comment: You cannot do it in a single expression without extra assignment or duplicating `<img>`

Comment: @zerkms ok cool, but I'm still not sure how it's meant to go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in writing imperative code, really:

```
const img = <img src={imageSrc} alt={imageAlt} title={imageTitle} />;

if (imageLink) {
    return <a href={imageLink}>{img}</a>;
}

return img;
```

Comment: ternary way: `return imageLink ? <a href="..">{img}</a> : img;`

Comment: @mickdev it does not add anything to the original code though :shrug: (other than making it harder to read)

Comment: I know, it's because the author was asking for ternary way to do it ^^

Comment: @mickdev I thought the OP wanted a single-expression way of doing it :shrug: But anyway, sorry :-)

Comment: @zerkms it's harder to read only if it's not **formatted properly**

Answer (score 0):

As @zerkms said, there's nothing wrong with an `if` statement.

But... what you could do is something like this:

```
const ConditionalLinkWrapper = ({ link, wrapper, children }) => 
  link ? wrapper(children) : children;
```

Your code then would use this reusable component like this:

```
const imageBlock = ({
  imageSrc,
  imageAlt,
  imageTitle,
  imageLink,
}: imageBlockProps) => (
  <ConditionalLinkWrapper
    link={imageLink}
    wrapper={children => <a href={imageLink}>{children}</a>}
  >
    <img src={imageSrc} alt={imageAlt} title={imageTitle} />
  </ConditionalLinkWrapper>
);
```

In my opinion, it's cleaner and easier to read than with an `if` statement, but that might not be the case for everyone!

I also like the fact that this is following the [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) pattern.

You can also reuse the `ConditionalLinkWrapper` component anywhere in your code if you need to.

Comment: "it's cleaner and easier to read" --- and it also is broken. Now curious how long it will take to find it in such a messy (subjective, I know) code. Now take a timer and honestly report it, without running it somewhere :-)

Comment: @zerkms: Not sure if that was the wrongly named prop but if that was the only issue (didn't see anything else tbh)... I don't really get the comment then :) Also, my mistake could be easily avoided with TS (also, not writing code directly inside SO editor could help). As I said, I find this pattern quite clear and useful to not write `if` statements over and over again in the entire codebase, but that's only my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended, but if you're really looking for a one-liner, check this out:

```
return ((img = <img src={imageSrc} alt={imageAlt} title={imageTitle} />) => 
  imageLink
    ? <a href={imageLink}>{img}</a>
    : img
)()
```